# Frameworks/Libraries & Game engines -- What's the difference

Tags: java, xna, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I've seen plenty of game programming frameworks, libraries, and engines but there seems to be a difference I can't put a finger on. It seems like frameworks are harder to work with than engines.

From what I understand (or think I understand) Frameworks are built using programming libraries, and game engines can be built using frameworks. I'm confused on the whole deal to be honest.

Is there some sort of heirarchy involved with these? There's a game engine I seen in Java called LibGDX, which is built on top of the LWJGL **and** JOGL, and can be used to make android games because It uses Google's Android framework as well, how is that possible?

I've also used the C# XNA framework, which can be used to make full blown games, and there are engines built on top of that, why would you need an engine on top of the XNA framework when you can build the game from the framework itself?

Also, I dont know much about Unity but it seems to be able to use three different languages as a game engine.

Comment: There's some answers to this on the Gamedev site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10770/whats-the-difference-between-a-library-and-an-engine/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library is just part that you use to build the final product. It usually is responsible for one particular thing like Math, Physics, Rendering, etc.

Framework is a bit bigger or can be just a synonym of Library. Framework can be all fundamentals necessary to build a game like Math, Physics, Rendering all together. For example XNA has fundamentals for Audio, Math, Graphics, Input, etc. With framework you have the basics but on low level usually you need to write a lot of code to make a game with a framework. In many cases you want to write a whole layer on top of the framework (it can be a whole Engine) in order to make a game with it.

Engine is much higher layer. With many of the game engines you don't have to write a single line of code to make a game (it may not be very innovative game but it will be a game). Engines usually come with game editor and other tools that are not part of your final game and often are data driven. You can just run the game editor and make a level or modify the winning logic and therefore make a whole new game.

Answer (score 4):

Going to start from the most basic based on what I understand.

A library is something extended into a program, a really common example would be a .dll file (Dynamic-link library) which extends functionality into the application it is being included in.  I tend to think of libraries as being similar in many ways to classes because they are extending existing functionality into something that does not natively have that functionality (I am kind of inexperienced with libraries so please correct me if I am wrong).  There is more to libraries then just this though so I will point you to wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_library

A framework is pretty simple to explain, it is **basically** a collection of libraries.  When you are referencing an object in XNA (say you want to make a StringBuilder), then the framework you are using references System.Text (EDIT: Which is part of the mscorelib) to access the class StringBuilder. So in this example (as Aleks pointed out) it goes StringBuilder (class) Text (namespace) System (another namespace) which is part of mscorelib (or the .NET library according to MSDN).

Game Engines are sort of similar to frameworks but they are a little more focused and refined.  In general I think a game engine includes things like resources, editors, built in functionality, and ect that you would not necessarily find in just XNA.  I think one of the biggest draws (from my understanding) to using a game engine is the resources included.  You don't need to create your own textures, they may have some models, sounds, animations.  It is a more complete set of tools for creating a video game as opposed to having to create all that stuff from scratch.  Again I will point you to wikipedia for more:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine

Comment: The framework example isn't accurate. StringBuilder is not part of XNA. System.Text is not a library. StringBuilder is a class, part of System.Text namespace, part of mscorelib (library), part of .NET Framework.

Comment: @Aleks MSDN disagrees with you about StringBuilder not being part of XNA http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @Derrick Right at the top of your link: `Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)`